# How do I get random excerpts to show in WordPress?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Good morning, I been trying to get an excerpt of a post to show random post excerpts on the homepage with no luck. My code looks like this:

```
    <?php
        $spotlight  = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'success-spotlight', 'posts_per_page' => 1,       'orderby' => 'rand' ) );
while ( $spotlight->have_posts() ) : $spotlight->the_post();
    $spotlight_title = get_the_title();
    $spotlight_excerpt = types_render_field("story-headline", array("raw"=>"true"));
    $spotlight_link = get_permalink();
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'spiffy-success-spotlight-`home');
        $spotlight_image = $thumb[0]; // thumbnail url
    }


endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
<?php

?>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance

Comment: what is the issue exactly ? here in your `WP_Query` you specify only to get one post, so it will not be random

Comment: @AhmadAssaf even when I change posts_per_page to a higher number like 5 for example, it will not randomly display posts

Comment: can you be more specific on what you want. so you want to show N random excerpts of your posts ?

Comment: @AhmadAssaf I need one post to display but randomly there's about 15 different posts for success spotlight. I need 1 to display randomly everytime the home page loads. Currently the same post only displays when the home page loads.

Comment: did the query_posts work ? @MikeL5799

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
query_posts('orderby=rand&showposts=1&post_type=success-spotlight');
```